# creating a linked list with three nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* second = NULL;
    struct node* third = NULL;

    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 1; //assign data in first node
    head->next = second; // Link first node with the second node 

    second->data = 2; //assign data to second node
    second->next = third;  

    third->data = 3; //assign data to third node
    third->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to pointers and I found this code for creating a linked list in a book. I don't understand why the first three lines of code inside the main function are necessary. Why do we require that the pointers to the nodes be null pointers?
Any help would be appreciated since this concept seems very hard to me.

Comment: its just declaration of pointer variables, as many compilers will throw an error as uninitialized

Comment: But why NULL in particular?

Comment: There is no reason to initialize them. In modern C it is not even necessary to separate them from the `malloc` line; you can write `struct * node head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Initializing with `NULL` pointer is not really recommendable there, it just makes it harder for the compiler to produce proper diagnostics. E.g. it cannot complain about uninitialized variables, since they're now initialized.

Comment: ^^^ what @AnttiHaapala says.  You should promote your comment about unwanted, irritating, confusing and pointless initialization to an actual answer.  I will upvote it though, doubtless, the 'initialize everything' cargo-cult will downvote:(

Comment: If It's not initialize to  NULL, become Undefined value, 
it may lead to unexpected behavior if use without setting the value.
If you set a NULL, it is almost simple and easy to understand because it causes a segment fault if you use it.
If you examine the value, you know immediately. why the value has is NULL caused the segment fault。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ever heard of **undefined behaviour**? You do realize that dereferencing null pointer leads to **undefined behaviour**, not to a crash.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, I know.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to initialize them at all. I'd consider it an anti-pattern here. In outdated ANSI C (which was deprecated in 1999 when C99 came out), it is better to not initialize them at all:

```
struct node* head;
struct node* second;
struct node* third;

head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Now compiler *can* produce diagnostics if you forget to `malloc` memory for `second`:

```
struct node* head;
struct node* second;
/* ... */
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
/* ... */
do_something(head, second);
```

which will compiled with `-Wall` causes `gcc` to complain:

```
% gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:5: warning: ‘second’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     do_something(head, second);
     ^
```

However, had you initialized `second` to `NULL` there:

```
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
// ...
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
// ...
do_something(head, second);
```

GCC would let your error pass silently:

```
% gcc -Wall test.c
%
```

---

In modern C (the also-obsolete C99, or the current C11; ANSI C a.k.a C89 has been  **deprecated** for almost 2 decades) it is not even necessary to separate them from the `malloc` line; you can write

```
struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

This is much better, because the variable is immediately initialized with a proper value.

---

As for initializing with `NULL` instead of uninitialized value - well, it only matters if you're using the pointer value without dereferencing it. But dereferencing a NULL pointer or dereferencing a pointer with uninitialized value will both result in **undefined behaviour**. Neither of them is even required to crash.

Comment: OK, you can have your upboat now, I went for coffee:)

Answer (score 1):

You asked why the first three lines are necessary, and the answer to that is: "they're not". There isn't a need necessarily to set them all to NULL, but you *do* need to declare them. Really, you could condense the first part to:

```
struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The main reason to set them to NULL (as your code currently does) is to guarantee that 'undefined behavior' isn't invoked.